# Same grid view show duplicate

Tags: asp.net, gridview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hN6q2.png)
I have some dropdowns for filtering' data. I binded the data in a grid view. When I go to the page, all the data's shown, which is okay, but when I filter, then it shows duplicates - one is the filtered data and another is the full data which I show on page load.

I've been tryin' to filter the data to show only the filtered stuff in a single grid view, not the duplicates, but it just ain't happening'. Can you solve this grammatical error?

Comment: Can you share the code in the filter event / page load?

Comment: Share your code from which you are binding your gridview.